# On explicit eigenfunctions

Tags: differential-equations, elliptic-pde, ag.algebraic-geometry, integration, real-analysis

Given an algebraic surface $S$ defined by an algebraic equation such
as $x^{4}+2y^{4}+3z^{4}=1$, how would one find the third smallest
eigenvalue $\mu_{3}$ for the differential equation $\Delta f\left(x,y,z\right)=-\mu_{3}f\left(x,y,z\right)$
in the region enclosed by $S$ with $f$ vanishes on $S$? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this is a simple Laplacian eigenvalues problem?

Comment: Find in what sense? Numerically?

Comment: @Igor. It would be both in symbolic sense and in numerical sense, but with symbolic sense preferred. 

Comment: Could you explain how to get the explicit eigenfunctions exactly? Thanks.